# angular-cli, Google Visualization Charts, SystemJS

Tags: angular, google-visualization, systemjs, angular-cli

I'm building a charts app with Angular 2 (angular-cli) and Google Charts.

Just putting the google-loader script tags in the index.html works in development mode, 
but when building for production (everything is bundled) I get an error that

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'arrayToDataTable' of undefined` when calling

`google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);`

The next thing I tried is putting the loader.js in the SystemJS config:

```
const map: any = {
    'google-visualization': 'https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'
};
```

importing it in `main.ts`

```
import 'google-visualization';
```

and loading the corechart package in `app.ts`

```
google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['corechart'],
    'language': 'pl'
});
```

Now I get an error saying

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.`

Is there any other way of loading the Google Visualization API without a proxy in between?